# When writing a Glimpse Plugin how do you add a clickable URL link?

Tags: plugins, glimpse

When writing a Glimpse Plugin how do you output a clickable link?  It appears to HTML encode all output.  I want to create a link in my plugin to connect to another page in the site to view more detailed information.

Also, is there any way to make the Core Trace plugin output a clickable link?

Answer (score 4):

You can write raw HTML output to a Glimpse Plugin (aka Tab) by surrounding the string with exclamation marks (`!`).

Here's an example. Typically you'd do something like this:

```
Trace.Write("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Link</a>");
```

Which would output: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>` in the trace tab.

To use "raw" HTML, add the exclamation marks:

```
Trace.Write("!<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Link</a>!");
```

Which will output: [Link](http://www.google.com) in the trace tab.